# Problems during booting - Error reading from disk/GRUB rescue

Tags: 14.04, boot, hardware

Sometimes, I cannot boot my OS (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and I always get different sort of error. Maybe you can help with identifying where is the problem. These crashes are becoming more frequent and I have no idea what is causing them.

Usually, I start my computer and everything starts smoothly and the OS boots up without any problem. But sometimes, strange things happen - and it is not even deterministic (different errors at different times). These are some of the symptoms:

1) Starting my computer -> straight into black screen with `Reading error` message (nothing more)

2) Starting my computer -> BIOS -> GRUB that offers several memories to boot the system from but when selecting my disc with OS, nothing happens and I go back into GRUB

3) Starting my computer -> loud beeping noise -> GRUB rescue

4) Starting my computer -> `error reading from hd0` error message (and sometimes GRUB rescue)

What is the cause of this? Usually, it starts working again when I restart the computer (sometimes I have to do it 5 times before it goes up again).

Could it be hardware oriented problem? Maybe related to the fact that I am using an SSD disk? Or maybe BIOS or GRUB oriented problem? Or is something wrong with the OS?

Thanks for any tips. My Linux skills are quite low so, please, try to explain some steps like you would to a beginner...

Comment: It really sounds like a problem in your disk.

Comment: I run some disc diagnostics via GRUB when I got offered that choice and it discovered no errors...